# N>Help with Passing Values from one Object picklist to another Object text

Tags: picklist, sobject, master-detail, junction-object

I have 3 objects **Contact**, **mList** and **mEvent**. mList is a junction object which has **master-detail relationships** to **both Contact and mEvent**. The **mEvent** has a **picklist** field called **Group_Level__c** (values 1,2,3,4) and **Contact** has **text** field called **Member_Level__c**.

My problem is that whenever I save/update a new **mEvent** record, I need the selected **mEvent.Group_Level__c** picklist value to be reflected to all **Contact.Member_Level__c** text values that are linked to it. (Contact.Member__Level__c values are **dependent** on mEvent.Group_Level__c value)

What is the best approach to achieve this?
(An mEvent record can be linked to thousands of Contact records at a time and vice versa.)

Answer (score 0):

write before update trigger on mevent object. now in this trigger whenwver Group level change tthen query on mcent object including the contact field . now store this value in contact and update all contact.

**Example**

```
List<mcent__c> mcentlist =[select Contact__c,mevent__c , mEvent.Group_Level__c from mcent__c where mevent__c ID IN : meveIdSet];
List<contact> conlist = new List<contact>();
for(mcent__c me : mcentlist )
{
     contact con = new contact(id = me.contact__c);
     con.Member_Level__c = Trigger.newMap.get(me.mevent__c).Group_Level__c;
     conlist.add(con);
}
update conlist;
```

As i am not sure about your field api name so check them also check some null pointer validation as well. This code will give you basic understanding.

Comment: @Tushar...what if the contact is linked with thousands of mEvent and an mEvent is linked to thousands of Contact...will it reach a governor limit or not? if so, what could be done to bypass that? thx so much

Comment: what is 'meveIdSet' in the query?

Comment: meveIdset is the set of id of mevent object. and yes it can hit the governer limit for that you need to break the code.

Comment: is it possible for you to give me the full trigger code (including the above)? I currently have small backgroup on triggers and I could use it for future references...

Comment: i realized my logic has a problem...if a contact is related to multiple events and have these corresponding selected picklist values:


(mEvent ,selected value)
eventA, 1;
eventB, 3;
eventC, 2;


I decided I will get my contact value from the selected picklist value of the latest event ex. eventB based on its datecreated